# swipe ViewPager error

Tags: android, android-viewpager

i am creating a swipe view pager and i gave downloaded a demo and i am using it in my project , but the problem is that this part of my code:

```
public class ViewPagerDemo extends Activity implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener, View.OnClickListener{

protected View view;
private ImageButton btnNext, btnFinish;
private ViewPager intro_images;
private LinearLayout pager_indicator;
private int dotsCount;
private ImageView[] dots;
private ViewPagerAdapter mAdapter;

private int[] mImageResources = {
        R.mipmap.abc1,
        R.mipmap.abc2,
        R.mipmap.abc3,
        R.mipmap.abc4,
        R.mipmap.abc5
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    // To make activity full screen.
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setReference();

  /*  toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);*/

}


public void setReference() {
    view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.playbutton,container);

    intro_images = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager_introduction);
    btnNext = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_next);
    btnFinish = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_finish);

    pager_indicator = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.viewPagerCountDots);

    btnNext.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnFinish.setOnClickListener(this);

    mAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(ViewPagerDemo.this, mImageResources);
    intro_images.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    intro_images.setCurrentItem(0);
    intro_images.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
    setUiPageViewController();
}
```

**@override and the R.layout**....container gets a red underline and this part **intro_images.setOnPageChangeListener(this);** has a line on it .
so when i run the project i get this error :

```
Error:(55, 40) Gradle: error: no suitable method found for inflate(int,int)
method LayoutInflater.inflate(int,ViewGroup) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; int cannot be converted to ViewGroup)
method LayoutInflater.inflate(XmlPullParser,ViewGroup) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; int cannot be converted to XmlPullParser)
```

and this is the xml file im using :

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager_introduction"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:listitem="@layout/pager_item" />

<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/viewPagerIndicator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center">

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/viewPagerCountDots"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />

    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_next"
            android:layout_width="42dip"
            android:layout_height="42dip"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_round_semitransperant"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_navigation_arrow_forward" />

    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_finish"
            android:layout_width="42dip"
            android:layout_height="42dip"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_round_semitransperant"
            android:contentDescription="Let's start"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_navigation_check"
            android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the inflate method wrong.

Use `view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.playbutton, container, false);`instead.

Comment: i did this , still no luck . both the override and the view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.playbutton, container, false); are underlined red

Comment: Is your `container` an instance of ViewGroup?

Comment: let me add my xml file to the question

Comment: i added the xml file and made more of the java file

Comment: I can't see what container is. And after adding the `false`, did you sync the project?

Comment: thanks for you answer , yes i did but i still get the gradle error above , where can i see the container type so i can tell you ?? sorry im new to android :(

Comment: i am usung this code from git : https://github.com/WasimMemon/Myapplications/tree/master/Tutorials but when i use it i get the error above

Comment: thank you so much i fixed the problem finally i had to change the container to null